# Android NavigationView setBackgroundTintList doesnt work

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview, material-components-android, android-navigationview

I want to set the selected items color and background in the NavigationDrawer.
It works fine with the text and icons, but not with the selected item background.

```java
ColorStateList textColors = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{ -android.R.attr.state_checked }, // unchecked
                        new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_checked }  // checked
                },
                new int[]{
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.menu_text_color),
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.md_black_1000)
                }
        );
 navigationView.setItemTextColor(textColors);
 navigationView.setItemIconTintList(textColors);
```

But when I want the background to change the same way, the CHECKED state doesnt work, only the unchecked state...

```java
  ColorStateList backgroundColors = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{ -android.R.attr.state_checked }, // unchecked
                        new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_checked } // checked
                },
                new int[]{
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.md_grey_400),
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.md_grey_700)
                }
        );

 navigationView.setBackgroundTintList(backgroundColors);


 navigationView.getMenu().findItem(/* menuitem id */).setChecked(true);
```

How can I set the background of the checked state menuitem, like the text and icon color?

Comment: check this--> https://github.com/andremion/Floating-Navigation-View/pull/6/files

Comment: This sets the whole background of the navigationview... I want to set ONLY the checked MenuItems background, thats why I wanted this checked and unchecked approach, like with the text and icons

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **`itemShapeFillColor`** attribute in your layout or in your style.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemShapeFillColor="@color/..."
    ../>
```

or use a custom style:

```
<style name="..." parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView" >
   <item name="itemShapeFillColor">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

It is the default selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Pay attention to use to the `itemBackground`.
It is set to `@null` to use a **shaped background programmatically** generated by `NavigationView` when `itemShapeAppearance` and/or `itemShapeAppearanceOverlay` is set (default behaviour).
This background is styled using the `itemShape*` attributes below. Setting `itemBackground` will overwrite the programmatic background and cause values set in the `itemShape*` attributes to be ignored.

Comment: How can I use this?
I created an XML file in drawable, and set it to the NavigationView's itemBackground, but it crashes:
 com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" >

Comment: There is no `app:itemShapeFillColor` in xml in the NavigationView  :(

Comment: @CookieMonster You have to use the version 1.1.0 of the material components library